# Generate series of numbers in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-office

I want to know how to generate the following series in Excel. I know that the fill series function only allows it be 1, 2, 3, 4...

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
.
.
.
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: would you be ok with putting in 1 and 1 in 2 cells, then putting in a formula that the cell=1+ the cell 2 above it? You could then drag that down as far as you wish, I would think.

Comment: so for example in a1 and a2 put 1. in a3 say =a1+1. Then grab the lower right corner of a3 drag down and fill away.

Comment: @JeremyKahan -- I recommend you post that as an answer.  I seriously think that's the quickest and easiest way to accomplish this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With thanks to @Hambone for encouragement, put 1 in cell A1, say, 1 in A2, and then in A3 say =A1+1. This formula in A3 is suitable for dragging and filling into as many cells below it as desired, and it will produce the desired sequence.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks.